# Is it better to create tables and add rows in code or put existing database to Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am wondering what is better.
I have to create database that contains 5 tables and almost each of them contains 100 rows.

I need to create it only once, but do you think is it better idea to do it in code or just use SQLiteBrowser and create this database and send it to App data?

I wanted to do it by code, make big insert method and put there all my rows I want to insert.

Comment: it's not large db, put it in data

Comment: yes, prefill data in an SQLite file and bundle it in the app. Be careful with the file format, keep in mind which is your minSDK version and create a compatible SQLite file for the SQLite engine bundled in the OS starting from that version.